# Is there any way that I can plot an XML file that contains thousands nodes by Python or R?

Tags: python, r, data-visualization, visualization, altair

I have a large XML that has many nodes. I only need a few data values from some of the nodes. However, I dont have any documents that explicitly introduce the structure of this XML file. So I am thinking to plot this file by Python or R. Is there a way? Where should I start?

Comment: Your question as asked does not qualify for Stack Overflow. You have to ask a **specific** question about a problem related to programming. Questions asking for a start, how to program in general, directions or general hints are considered too broad. And BTW on Stack Overflow your questions will be judged by others and if they don't fit the rules they can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Python's [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) module is a good tool for working with XML.

Comment: Thank you! I am looking into it now.